# Is Silverlight more lucrative than ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Lately I've seen an lot of Silverlight jobs being advertised, with very high rates.

Is this just temporary because Silverlight developers are in scarce supply at the moment? Or is there something about Silverlight development that makes it better paid than normal .NET or web development?

Or do you think Silverlight will, in the long-term, be a more valuable skill to have than normal, standards-compliant web development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think no particular technology framework will be valuable in the long-term.  That's why having blinders like this is dangerous.  The important thing is to stay on your toes (constantly learning new things) and  to understand the general overriding principles that never go away.

Comment: I agree with that principle wholeheartedly.

However if you're in the contracting game, it's often important to specialize, in order to have all the right "keywords" on your resume to appease the technically inept higher-up's.

Comment: It's not just the technically incompetent higher-ups that need to see the right things on a contractor's resume.  If I'm hiring for a permanent position, I'm fine with the right person having a learning curve, because we're both in this for the long haul.  But if I'm hiring a contractor, I want to make sure that person has the necessary skills right out the gate.  I don't want a contractor I've hired to do 3 months of Silverlight work learning Silverlight on my dime.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right that the immediate pay scale is based on the freshness of the technology and the limited supply of skilled developers in that field. As more developers enter the field the prices will settle down - just like they did for Flash.

IMHO as the field matures you'll begin to see more and more separation of LOB developers that expose models to a Silverlight UI that is created by specialized De'v'signers. Of course really good developers in any technology will always demand higher pay.

Answer (score 0):

i think its new and yes due to that it has more attraction and appears like is creating a hype.
but its still a premature technology and requires lots of time to br proven worth as compared to asp.net the job rate you are seeing is just due to reason that there are very less number of silverlight developers right now.

Answer (score 0):

i think its new and yes due to that it has more attraction and appears like is creating a hype. but its still a premature technology and requires lots of time to br proven worth as compared to asp.net the job rate you are seeing is just due to reason that there are very less number of silverlight developers right now.